# Using variables in body_filter_by_lua_block

Tags: nginx

I am new to nginx, and I need to return altered request and from my understanding it is made in body_filter_by_lua_block scope by setting ngx.arg[1]. This is a simple base example of my usecase:

```
server {
listen       80;
server_name  localhost;

location / {

    body_filter_by_lua_block {
      ngx.arg[1] = '{ "Subject": "someval" }'
      ngx.arg[2] = true
    }
}
```

}

My question is, how can "someval" be turned into a variable, i.e:

```
server {
listen       80;
server_name  localhost;

location / {
    set $someval "hello";
    body_filter_by_lua_block {
      ngx.arg[1] = '{ "Subject": "$someval" }'
      ngx.arg[2] = true
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Your nginx variable is available for get and set in the lua block with ngx.var.someval.